# Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' with Android Studio Virtual Device

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I can't setup properly what I am doing, let's explain as much as I can : I work with someone who started an Ignite project with the Andross package, I cloned the repo and tried to run the app using [this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment), I did everything properly and was able to run my virtual device, but I had to `chmod 777` my `node_modules/` and my `android/` for some reasons, and yet it won't work, I read [here](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/510) that i had to `npm i jetifier` but it didn't do much, tbh I have no idea what I'm doing, I really require help.

This is what I get when trying to `react-native run-android` :

```
react-native run-android
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - react-native-vector-icons: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - react-native-device-info (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-device-info")
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
  - react-native-i18n (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-i18n")
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1007 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:3: error: package androidx.core.util does not exist
import androidx.core.util.Pools;
                         ^
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:19: error: package Pools does not exist
  private static final Pools.SynchronizedPool<RNGestureHandlerEvent> EVENTS_POOL =
                            ^
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:3: error: package androidx.core.util does not exist
import androidx.core.util.Pools;
                         ^
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:19: error: package Pools does not exist
  private static final Pools.SynchronizedPool<RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent> EVENTS_POOL =
                            ^
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:20: error: package Pools does not exist
          new Pools.SynchronizedPool<>(TOUCH_EVENTS_POOL_SIZE);
                   ^
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:20: error: package Pools does not exist
          new Pools.SynchronizedPool<>(TOUCH_EVENTS_POOL_SIZE);
                   ^
Note: /home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
6 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:3: error: package androidx.core.util does not exist
import androidx.core.util.Pools;
                         ^
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:19: error: package Pools does not exist
  private static final Pools.SynchronizedPool<RNGestureHandlerEvent> EVENTS_POOL =
                            ^
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:3: error: package androidx.core.util does not exist
import androidx.core.util.Pools;
                         ^
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:19: error: package Pools does not exist
  private static final Pools.SynchronizedPool<RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent> EVENTS_POOL =
                            ^
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:20: error: package Pools does not exist
          new Pools.SynchronizedPool<>(TOUCH_EVENTS_POOL_SIZE);
                   ^
/home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:20: error: package Pools does not exist
          new Pools.SynchronizedPool<>(TOUCH_EVENTS_POOL_SIZE);
                   ^
Note: /home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
6 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:621:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
    at buildAndRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:169:41)
    at then.result (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:135:12)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I will gladly give any other information you guys need to help me.

Comment: please show how you linked `react-native-gesture-handler`

Comment: I didn't link anything since I'm not the one who started the project :(

Comment: as you can see in the error, it says ` Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.` So probably there is some error in you java files.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of react-native requires AndroidX. you have to jetify the project, until the maintainers updates their package, using:

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier && npx jetify
```

after that just

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: Did you try also doing react-native start in a terminal and npx run-android?

Comment: react-native start gives me 


`error listen EADDRINUSE :::8081. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.`

and npx run-android gives me this


`npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: run-android@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/justicemadness/.npm/_logs/2019-07-22T13_50_47_174Z-debug.log
Install for run-android@latest failed with code 1`

Comment: You probably have a metro bundler running somewhere, try to find it. A process is already taking port 8081

Comment: yeah port 8081 was running `./studio.sh`, I stopped it and did react-native start again, which gives me this `You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide. Running Metro Bundler on port 8081. Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer. https://github.com/facebook/react-native
Looking for JS files in
   /home/justicemadness/Documents/Work/Ideel
Loading dependency graph, done.`

Comment: After that run npx run-android